# Tableau exclude column in calculation

Tags: tableau-api

```
month   name    fruit eaten amount paid
Jan-19  john    apple   3
Jan-19  jim       orange    7
Jan-19  king    apple   6
Feb-19  john    berry   5
Feb-19  jim     mango   7
Feb-19  king    pawpaw  8
Mar-19  john    apple   5
Mar-19  jim      melon  7
Mar-19  king    lemon   9
```

solution I want:
Name    latest fruit eaten (Mar-19) Year to date Total spent by Name

```
john    apple   13  
jim.    melon   21  
king    lemon   23
```

Please I want to summarize the values based in the image only include the maximum or latest value of one column.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Place month filter and select `March`, now place name and fruit on rows.

Create a calculated field `amount` and write below:

```
{ FIXED [fruit]:SUM([amount])}
```

Place it on marks

Edit-------------------------------------------------------------------

[image]

calculated field:

[image]

Comment: I know it's a lot to ask but can I get a screenshot?

Comment: Thank you. When April 2019 data is added will the "latest fruit eaten" update to that of April? That's is the goal.

Comment: @lilchill yes it will added till april